# MQTT Callback function don't called

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I'm doing a device to recongnize NFC cards with an Arduino UNO, a CC3000 wifi shield, and a PN532 NFC shield. That's ok.

So, I created a sketch with this library: https://github.com/nathanchantrell/pubsubclient

I subscribed a topic /ocean/nfc/porta. When I publish a message to it, the callback function isn't called. Moreover, when it takes a card ID it publishs to a topic sometimes then don`t work more. How to solve it?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <cc3000_PubSubClient.h>

#define PN532_IRQ   (4)
#define PN532_RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

char cardID[ 16 ];

Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
// for Zero, output on USB Serial console, remove line below if using programming port to program the Zero!
// also change #define in Adafruit_PN532.cpp library file
   #define Serial SerialUSB
#endif

// These are the interrupt and control pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   2  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
// These can be any two pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  7
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10

// Use hardware SPI for the remaining pins
// On an UNO, SCK = 13, MISO = 12, and MOSI = 11
Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT, SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER);

#define WLAN_SSID       "Ocean Convidado"
#define WLAN_PASS       "ocean2901"
//#define WLAN_SSID       "Ocean Lab"
//#define WLAN_PASS       "ocean3101"

// Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2

Adafruit_CC3000_Client client;

// We're going to set our broker IP and union it to something we can use
union ArrayToIp {
  byte array[4];
  uint32_t ip;
};

ArrayToIp server = { 25, 0, 25, 172 };

void callback (char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len) {


    Serial.println(F("CALLBACK"));
/*
    char payload_buffer[20];


    if (strcmp (topic,"/ocean/nfc/porta") == 0) {

        byteToChar(payload, payload_buffer, len);

        if (strcmp(payload_buffer, "permitir") == 0) {
          Serial.println(F("Abreeee!!!!!!"));
        } else {
          Serial.println(F("Não abre!!!!!!"));
        }

    }*/
}

cc3000_PubSubClient mqttclient(server.ip, 1883, callback, client, cc3000);

void setup(void) {

  #ifndef ESP8266
    while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
  #endif
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("Hello OCEAN NFC Reader!"));

  Serial.println(F("Inicializando NFC Reader...."));

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print(F("Didn't find PN53x board"));
    while (1); // halt
  }
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print(F("Found chip PN5")); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print(F("Firmware ver. ")); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print(F(".")); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println(F("Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...\n\n"));

  Serial.println(F("Inicializando Wifi CC3000"));

  displayDriverMode();

  Serial.println(F("\nInicializando o CC3000 ..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Nao foi possivel inicializar o CC3000! Os cabos estao conectados corretamente?"));
    for(;;);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(F("Carregou"));
  }

  uint16_t firmware = checkFirmwareVersion();
  if ((firmware != 0x113) && (firmware != 0x118)) {
    Serial.println(F("Versao do firmware errada!"));
    for(;;);
  }

  displayMACAddress();

  Serial.println(F("\nDeletando perfis de conexoes antigas"));
  if (!cc3000.deleteProfiles()) {
    Serial.println(F("Falhou!"));
    while(1);
  }

  /* Attempt to connect to an access point */
  char *ssid = WLAN_SSID;             /* Max 32 chars */
  Serial.print(F("\nTentando conectar-se a(o) ")); Serial.println(ssid);

  /* NOTE: Secure connections are not available in 'Tiny' mode! */
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Falhou!"));
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Conectado!"));

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  Serial.println(F("Requisitando DHCP"));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP()) {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }

  /* Display the IP address DNS, Gateway, etc. */  
  while (!displayConnectionDetails()) {
    delay(1000);
  }

   // connect to the broker
   if (!client.connected()) {
     client = cc3000.connectTCP(server.ip, 1883);
     Serial.println(F("Conectando em TCP"));
   }

   // did that last thing work? sweet, let's do something
   if(client.connected()) {
    if (mqttclient.connect("ArduinoUnoClient-CC3000-A2", "iotocean", "NZZOLd0O66oLS0vpajiA123")) {
      Serial.println(F("Publicando"));
      mqttclient.publish("/ocean/nfc/debug","A2 está online");
      mqttclient.subscribe("/ocean/nfc/porta");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println(F("Ouve um erro ao conectar-se ao broker"));
    }
   } 

}


void loop(void) {

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("Entrei no loop\n"));
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);

  if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println(F("Found an ISO14443A card"));
    Serial.print(F("  UID Length: "));Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print(F("  UID Value: "));
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);

    if (uidLength == 4)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
      uint32_t cardid = uid[0];
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[1];
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[2];  
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[3]; 
      Serial.print(F("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card #"));
      Serial.println(cardid);


          // Testa se ainda esta conectado
          if (!client.connected()) {
            Serial.println(F("!client.connected()"));
             client = cc3000.connectTCP(server.ip, 1883);

             if(client.connected()) {
               if (mqttclient.connect("ArduinoUnoClient-Office-A2")) {
                  mqttclient.publish("/ocean/nfc/debug","A2 está novamente online");
               }
             } 
          } else {
            Serial.println(F("else !client.connected()"));
            // as per comment from LS_dev, platform is int 16bits
            sprintf(cardID,"%lu", cardid);


            mqttclient.publish("/ocean/nfc/id", cardID); delay(1000);
          }
          //delay(1000);

    }
    Serial.println(F(""));
  }


  Serial.println(F("Sai do loop\n"));
}

void displayDriverMode(void)
{
  #ifdef CC3000_TINY_DRIVER
    Serial.println(F("CC3000 is configure in 'Tiny' mode"));
  #else
    Serial.print(F("RX Buffer : "));
    Serial.print(CC3000_RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    Serial.println(F(" bytes"));
    Serial.print(F("TX Buffer : "));
    Serial.print(CC3000_TX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    Serial.println(F(" bytes"));
  #endif
}

void charToByte(char* chars, byte* bytes, unsigned int count){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      bytes[i] = (byte)chars[i];
}

void byteToChar(byte* bytes, char* chars, unsigned int count){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];
}

uint16_t checkFirmwareVersion(void)
{
  uint8_t major, minor;
  uint16_t version;

#ifndef CC3000_TINY_DRIVER  
  if(!cc3000.getFirmwareVersion(&major, &minor))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve the firmware version!\r\n"));
    version = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("Firmware V. : "));
    Serial.print(major); Serial.print(F(".")); Serial.println(minor);
    version = major; version <<= 8; version |= minor;
  }
#endif
  return version;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the 6-byte MAC address of the CC3000 module
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void displayMACAddress(void)
{
  uint8_t macAddress[6];

  if(!cc3000.getMacAddress(macAddress))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve MAC Address!\r\n"));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("MAC Address : "));
    cc3000.printHex((byte*)&macAddress, 6);
  }
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Tries to read the IP address and other connection details
*/
/**************************************************************************/
bool displayConnectionDetails(void)
{
  uint32_t ipAddress, netmask, gateway, dhcpserv, dnsserv;

  if(!cc3000.getIPAddress(&ipAddress, &netmask, &gateway, &dhcpserv, &dnsserv))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve the IP Address!\r\n"));
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(F("\nIP Addr: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(ipAddress);
    Serial.print(F("\nNetmask: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(netmask);
    Serial.print(F("\nGateway: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(gateway);
    Serial.print(F("\nDHCPsrv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dhcpserv);
    Serial.print(F("\nDNSserv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dnsserv);
    Serial.println();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Output of Arduino IDE:

> O sketch usa 28.438 bytes (88%) de espaço de armazenamento para
>   programas. O máximo são 32.256 bytes. Variáveis globais usam 1.546
>   bytes (75%) de memória dinâmica, deixando 502 bytes para variáveis
>   locais. O máximo são 2.048 bytes. Pouca memória disponível, problemas
>   de estabilidade podem ocorrer.

Comment: I don't see any attempts to publish to `/ocean/nfc/porta` in your code. You are publishing from another node? Your broker is local? Post everything you get in the serial monitor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem. There is a bug on CC3000, so need to use WatchDog to reset for each while.